# Changeable barcode Code 128 B is not centralized in any circumstances

Tags: command, barcode, zpl, code128

Using barcodes with different length (12 chars or 16 chars). Cannot find a tool to centralize the barcode depending on the length. If I set 16 chars by default, and then I will need to print a 12 char barcode, it will not centralize but cut from the right. Any ideas how can i centralize it just like the ^FB command for text fields?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is one of the major short-comings of ZPL.  It does not support center alignment of barcodes.  The solution I use is to calculate the length of the symbol (it's not too hard) and manually center it.  I can post some javascript code if you would like to see how the length calc is done.

Comment: Eh it'd not be so useful as if there could be any command in ZPL, anyways thanks for the reply )